# Python: How to use asyncio with huge csv-files to send asynchronous requests from loops?

Tags: python, asynchronous, beautifulsoup, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I want to go through a huge list of urls and send requests to them asynchronously. 
Since the CSV-file with the urls is too big to load it at once, I would like to read the lines row by row, and each time the row is loaded, it should start a request and save the result to a file.

My problem is that if I understood it right when I use `asyncio.gather` all tasks have to be collected at once.

It would be great if you could tell me how to change my code, to get it to send asynchronous requests for each row of the csv file.

Here is the code I am stuck with:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import async_timeout

import csv

async def fetch( session, url ):
    async with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return response
        except Exception as e:
            print(str( e ))
            return False

async def write_result( result ):
    with open( 'results.csv', 'a' ) as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer( csv_file )
        writer.writerow( result )

async def validate_page( session, url ):
    response = await fetch( session, url )
    await write_result( response )

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with open('urls.csv') as csv_file:
            for row in csv.reader( csv_file ):
                await validate_page( session, row )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Note, what should be clarified is whether the processed urls need to be saved into the resulting csv file in the same order they were read - that's the crucial condition

Comment: They don't have to be in the same order, since I am filtering int he process of validating them anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To process each line from csv file asynchronously use the following approach.

A bunch of optimizations and restructuring of your current approach:

- no need to create `csv.reader` for csv input file if it contains only *url* on each separate line (just traverse though a file object)
- no need to wrap with additional `async with async_timeout.timeout(10)` as `aiohttp.ClientSession` itself has `timeout` option
- definitely no need to construct a new `writer = csv.writer( csv_file )` for each processed url (with consequent result) - create `writer` object just once (ensuring graceful writing with [asyncio.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#lock) - see below)

---

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

import csv

async def fetch(session, url):
    try:
        async with session.get(url, timeout=10) as response:
            return await response.text()
    except Exception as e:
        print(url, str(e))
        return False


async def write_result(result, writer):
    async with asyncio.Lock():   # lock for gracefully write to shared file object
        res = [<needed parts from result, >] # <- adjust a resulting list of strings
        writer.writerow(res)


async def validate_page(session, url, writer):
    res = await fetch(session, url)
    if res:
        await write_result(res, writer)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with open('urls.csv') as csv_in, open('results.csv', 'a') as csv_out:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=',')
            aws = [validate_page(session, url.strip(), writer) for url in csv_in]
            await asyncio.gather(*aws)
            print('!--- finished processing')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: That looks great, I will test it out with my file later today! The CSV-file actually has a couple of columns, but let's suggest the first column is the URL. I guess I just replace 
`aws = [validate_page(session, url.strip(), writer) for url in csv_in]` with
`aws = [validate_page(session, row[0].strip(), writer) for row in csv_in]`, correct?

Comment: But isn't the script still loading the >10M lines of the CSV-file into the aws variable, before starting to send requests?
Wouldn't there be a way to send the requests while reading the file line by line? I am just afraid of memory overflows if I load the whole CSV into a variable.

Comment: @Felix, that's the obvious cost, if you can not go into parallelization (with asyncio or threading) - then your way is sequential approach. That's obvious that with parallel approaches the data is dispersed among different routines or threads/processes

Comment: @Felix, your question stated "to get it to send asynchronous requests for each row of the csv file". The thing is not about memory saving but increasing speed and time performance